# How to configure experation and generation of new access token for login with Spring boot and OAuth2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've implemented Spring Boot with OAuth 2.0 authorization.

When I call /oauth/token endpoint I receive next output:

```
 `{
    "access_token": "03497838-790f-495f-91f4-029628ad084b",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "386ce1bd-5f76-4ea5-9091-5b46cec5429d",
    "scope": "tester"
}`
```

Problem is that I want to receive new access token at least every hour. I saw that there is possibility to configure "expire_in" but how should I do it?

I've tried to add token validity, but it didn't help

```
    @Bean
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService());
            //tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(endpoints.getTokenEnhancer());
            tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(10);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {

    endpoints
        .approvalStoreDisabled()
        //.approvalStore(approvalStore())
        .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenServices(tokenServices())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(restUserDetailsService);
}
```

I ran different configs, sometimes it disables token, but newer creates new one.

I found that default expiration is 12 hours which is too long for me.

Is there any way specify when Spring consider access token as not valid and create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you want expire you token, then you need to set validation token period
in db table in column access_token_validity table oauth_client_details. Then received token will be with section "expires_in" and after expire time you will get new token.